# Maze Solving From All Start Points

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Recently I came across a problem that stated;
Assume a maze having characters `*`,`.`,`C` .`*` represents walls and `.`/`C` are allowed. There is only one point which is marked `C`. Now given a bot stands on any of the allowed points, there exists a series of commands (for example `LDDRU` or `LLLRRDU`,etc.) such that if the bot starts from any allowed point, it passes through `C` at least once.
Eg:

```
******
*.C..*
**.***
*....*
******
```

Command: `RLLURUU`

Now I know how to solve a maze using DFS/BFS(for shortest path). But can anyone provide a hint on how I shall proceed problems like this?
EDIT: if the next move is into walls / outside maze, it is ignored. And as usual `L` IS LEFT `R` IS RIGHT `U` IS UP `D` IS DOWN.

Comment: The furthest you can move horizontally is 3 steps; so after e.g; LLL, you can only be at three positions in the grid; after another R, you can be in three positions in the vertical corridor; after UU you're sure to have passed the C. So in general: make a number of moves that reduce the number of positions you could be in, then keep track of all your possible robots, and make each go through C, by using the "if there's a wall, the robot doesn't move" rule. Each time two possible robots end up on the same square, remove one of them.

Comment: @m69,thanks for answering. But to be more clear, can you use the example given and explain your logic arriving to the answer....thank you!

Comment: There are 9 possible positions in 3 rows; after LLL any robot would be in the leftmost position in its row, so now you only have 3 possible postions; after another R, the 3 robots would be in the second-left position (vertical corridor); after UU they would all end up on the C.

Comment: So you start with as many "virtual" robots as there are positions, and then any robot that runs into another robot is removed, and any robot that passes through C is removed, until you have no robots left (meaning all have passed through C).

Comment: @m69, thanks...understood!

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you can't just start at C and work the problem backwards. So if RLLURUU is the path from the bot to C, then DDLDRRL would be the path from C to the robot.

Comment: @JimMischel The (not really clearly formulated) question is about finding a sequence which works from every starting position, not about identifying the starting position for a given sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to the concept of [*synchronizing words*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronizing_word) or *reset sequences* for finite automata. You can imagine building an automaton where

1. each open space, plus C, is a state;
2. each state other than C transitions to itself for every move that hits a wall;
3. each state other than C transitions to a neighboring open state in the indicated direction if there's an open spot in that direction; and
4. the C state transitions to itself on all moves.

Given this automaton, you're now looking for a sequence that takes every state to the C state, hence the connection to synchronizing words. There are a number of algorithms for finding synchronizing words, and any of them could be adapted to solve this particular problem. One option would be to [build the power automaton from the original automaton](https://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/atc-2011/Raghu-DFA%20Synchronization.pdf) and to look for a path from the start state to the C state, which (I believe) ends up being a theoretically optimal version of the comment talking about collapsing virtual robots together (in that it will always find the optimal path.)

Comment: "build a power automaton" - that's exponential, even if we only build accessible nodes. Anything faster? I don't even need the shortest synchronizing word.

Comment: You linked to the mobile version of wikipedia. Please fix.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you didn't need the shortest solution. The power automaton construction is worst-case exponential for arbitrary automata, but I'm not sure that the specific automata in this cas would actually trigger it. I'm going to have to think about that one. There are other approaches that are known to be worst-case polynomial time, though I'm less familiar with them.

Comment: @JanDvorak Also, I fixed the link. Sorry about that!